kableExtra is turning embedded html into escaped text
I am creating a html page in knitr. However, kableExtra is turning embedded html into escaped text.
Here is a MWE for the issue.
---
title: "Animals"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: TRUE
    toc_float: TRUE
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
require(knitr)
require(tidyverse)
require(formattable)
``\`

```{r animal_table, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
animal <- tibble(animal=c("dog","cat"), height=c(18,25), weight=c(10,12)) 

animal |> 
  mutate(height = color_tile("white","#DE8C59")(height)) |> 
  knitr::kable(
  col.names=c('Animal','Height','Weight'),
  escape = F
) |> 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
``\`

Animal  Height  Weight
dog <span style="display: block; padding: 0 4px; border-radius: 4px; background-color: #ffffff">18</span>   10
cat <span style="display: block; padding: 0 4px; border-radius: 4px; background-color: #de8c59">25</span>   12

However, if you comment out the line
#  kableExtra::kable_styling()

The table appears correctly.
Thanks in advance.

Unable to reproduce: could not find function "color_tile"

please supply the R chunk options as well in the MWE.

Sorry @Limey, edited to include the required package, formattable

Apols @Julian it was hidden by the markdown S

You should always use kableExtra::kbl() rather than knitr::kable() if you want to apply kableExtra styling.
It's also a good idea to use FALSE instead of F, because F is a variable that can have a value other than FALSE.
In your example that would be
```{r animal_table, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
animal <- tibble(animal=c("dog","cat"), height=c(18,25), weight=c(10,12)) 

animal |> 
  mutate(height = color_tile("white","#DE8C59")(height)) |> 
  kableExtra::kbl(
    col.names=c('Animal','Height','Weight'),
    escape = FALSE
  ) |> 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```



Thankyou for this
